DataTables: get the row number of a paginated result from a php script
I have an index.html page showing a table where the results are obtained by DataTables with server-side processing.
The results are paginated, and each row has 8 columns: the first column shows an ID number, named idNumber (which is the primary key of a mysql table named messages) the second column shows an integer number, named reportNumber which is a foreign key in messages; this number is formatted as a link that opens a modal window with id="modalreports". Whatever reportNumber you click, always the same modal window is opened.
The modal window displays a table with id="tableReports" and the results are obtained and paginated by DataTables Ajax call with server-side processing, where a PHP script getReports.php is called.
The following is the code:
        var tabreps = $('#tableReports').DataTable({
            'processing': true,
            'serverSide': true,
            'serverMethod': 'post',
            'cache': false,
            'ajax': {
                'url':'getReports.php'
            },
            'columnDefs': [
                { className: 'dt-center', targets: [0] }
            ],
            "columns" : [
                {data: 'reportNumber',
                 render: function(data, type, row) {                            
                            var numRep = row.reportNumber;
                            
                            return '<input type="radio" name="radiobutton_report" value="'+numRep+'" id="id_radiobutton_report_' + numRep + '">&nbsp;&nbsp;' + numRep;
                         }
                },
                {data: 'reportDetail'} 
                ],
                "order": [[0, "asc"]]                    
        });

Inside getReports.php, the following mysql select is executed:
SELECT reportNumber,reportDetail FROM reports;

the SELECT gives 25000 rows; the result is formatted according to the SSP::simple method in the POST data Server-side example. The rows inside the modal window are paginated, and each row has two columns (according to the script above):

the first column shows a radiobutton with name radiobutton_report and reportNumber as a value
the second column shows a text (reportDetail)

From the main page, if I click on the link having i.e. 14816 as a report number, I would like that the modal window opens at the page showing the radiobutton with 14816 as a value, and checked.
I managed to pass the report number from the main page to the modal window (which is assigned to a variable reportNumberFromMainPage) on client-side, but didn't manage to have the page including the radiobutton with its report number displayed.
I put the following code
var totalRowsFromMysql = tabreps.page.info().recordsTotal; 

to obtain all of the rows from the mysql table (25000), but using the page.info() properties I only get information on the first page.
I also tried the following code to obtain the page number
var indexReport = tabreps.column(0, {order: 'current'}).data().indexOf(reportNumberFromMainPage);
if (indexReport >= 0) {
  var pageLength = tabreps.page.info().length;
  var pageNumber = Math.floor(indexReport / pageLength) + 1;
  console.log("clicked on report number " +  reportNumberFromMainPage + '; found at page ' + pageNumber);
}

but always get indexReport = -1. I know that server-side processing only sends to the client a number of data filtered according to the page, number of rows for page (default: 10), but I wonder if there is a DataTables parameter, as well as page.info().recordsTotal, which sends back an absolute row index and not the current page row index.
Thanks to everybody could give me some helpful hints or suggestions.

"and the result is sent back to the client (25000 rows)" - No it isn't, not if you are using server-side processing correctly. If you are using server-side processing correctly, the server should only be sending one page of data to the browser (the current page requested by the user, based on their sorting/filtering/pagination choices). So the browser will get 10 rows of data (or however many you show per page) - but not all 25,000 records. That is the whole point of server-side processing.

Server-side processing guide.

@andrewJames sorry, I explained myself badly. I know that by server-side processing, only 10 rows of data are sent to the client; I thought that, as if the total row number is sent back (25000 rows, which goes over 10 results), maybe it was also possible to get  the index of the report number  passed to the modal window  placed over the first 10 results.
Is not possible to get any information over the first 10 rows by using server-side processing?

OK, you should edit your question, in that case - don't just write a comment.

"found at page x": The value of x is going to be different for the same report number depending on how the user sorts and fliters the data, so I don't see how "found at page x" is of any use to anyone (but perhaps it is)...  Maybe I have not understood what specific question you are asking, but console.log( my_table.page.info().page +1 ); works for me. It tells me the current page number. Put it in a re-draw event to get the latest page number.
